# Generating all letter combinations of a set of letters in Python

Tags: python

Which code best generates all 3-letter combinations of a given set of letters in Python? I want to output something like this:
`'AAA', 'AAB', 'AAC', 'AAD', 'AAE', 'AAF', 'AAG', 'AAH', 'AAI', 'AAJ', 'AAK', 'AAL', 'AAM'...'ZZX', 'ZZY', 'ZZZ'`

Answer (score 1):

[itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) is a natural choice since these are essentially products drawn from a set of letters.

```
import string,itertools

words = [''.join(letters) for letters in itertools.product(string.ascii_uppercase,repeat = 3)]

print(words[:5]) #['AAA', 'AAB', 'AAC', 'AAD', 'AAE']
print(words[-5:]) #['ZZV', 'ZZW', 'ZZX', 'ZZY', 'ZZZ']
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it easy with for loops.

```
combinations = []
letters = ['A','B','C',....,'Z']
for letter1 in letters:
    code = ''
    code = code + letter1
    for letter2 in letters:
       code = code + letter2 
       for letter3 in letters:
           code = code + letter3
           combinations.append(code)
```

Comment: This code gets errors.

Comment: @Poiponen This was just an example (psudo code ish). What is the error?

Comment: It shows error message when I run the code.

Comment: @Poiponen yeah but what is the error message. diffucult to help without it. The itertools solution should also work

Comment: It is    
  File "main.py", line 2
    letters = ['A','B','C',....,'Z']
                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: You have to actually write the letters from A-Z, cant have ...

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `itertools.combinations_with_replacement` method

```py
import itertools

for conv in itertools.combinations_with_replacement("abcdefg",r=3):
    print(conv)
```

where `r` is the size of every combination.